# Having trouble reloading tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having trouble reloading the tableView. When my `firebaseService.getAllPosts()` method runs, it gives me the two posts in the database (as intended). I can tell this because when the `didSet` print runs, it gives me the correct count. However, because I know the tableview is set before the method gets run, I know I need to reload the tableview to update the count in my datasource. There-in lies the issue. I put the `posts` variable outside of my class on purpose so it could be accessed from every class. (If this is not a good practice, let me know.)

Where can I run `tableView.reloadData()` so my tableView datasource updates and gives me the correct could of `posts`? I've tried putting `FeedController().tableView.reloadData()` in the didSet and I've tried putting it in `viewDidLoad()` but neither of these worked. I've also tried adding a variable called `_posts` and setting it equal to `posts` and adding `didSet` to that with `tableView.reloadData()` inside the `didSet` but that doesn't work either.

```
class FeedController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    let cellId = "PhotoCell"
    let textCellId = "TextCell"
    let firebaseService = FirebaseService.sharedInstance
    static let sharedFeedInstance = FeedController()
    var posts = [Post]() {
     didSet {
      tableView.reloadData()
      print(posts.count)
      }
  }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firebaseService.getAllPosts()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        print("sections: \(posts.count)")
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let post:Post? = posts[indexPath.section]


        if let _ = post?.imageContentName {
            let photoFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedTVCellWithPhoto
            photoFeedCell?.post = post
            return photoFeedCell!
        }

        let textFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.textCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedTVCellText
        textFeedCell?.post = post
        return textFeedCell!
    }
}
```

**Update 1: getAllPosts method from FirebaseService class**

```
    func getAllPosts() {
        let postRef = ref.child("posts")
        postRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
//            print(snapshot.value)
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)
                        FeedController.sharedFeedInstance.posts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is that you need to execute the `reloadData` in the context of the view controller that is on screen; `FeedController().tableView.reloadData()` creates a new instance of `FeedController`, which doesn't help.  One way you can get what you want is to post an NSNotification from your `didSet` and have the interested view controllers subscribe to that.  And yes, the global variable is a bad idea. Create a singleton class or create a single instance and pass it to each of your view controllers

Comment: You need to be able to know when `getAllPosts` finishes, in order to call `reloadData` then. How does `getAllPosts` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, you are addressing the methods and properties of `FeedController` the wrong way. Every time that you use `FeedController()` in your code you should be using `self`.

The following two paragraphs are a refresher about class and instance methods and properties. Feel free to ignore them if it's something that's already in your radar:

- If a method or property belongs to an instance (that is, it may vary from instance to instance) you call it with `self.property` or `self.method()`, although often you can drop the `self.` as long as it does not create ambiguity.
- If a method or property belongs to the whole class (and therefore it is declared as `static let`, `static var` or `static func`) then you would call it with `NameOfTheClass.property` or `NameOfTheClass.method()`. In your case, you would call it `FeedController.property` or `FeedController.method()`. That is, **without the trailing parentheses**. In any case, class methods and properties should be used sparingly and would probably not be appropriate in this situation.

Having settled that, we have the question of how to reload the data. If you move `posts` inside `FeedController` (making the array an instance variable) and add `tableView.reloadData()` (without the `self.`) to the `didSet()` of `posts`, you should be good, notwithstanding other unrelated code smells that others have highlighted and you should try to fix, but those should not affect your ability to reload the data.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It really helps. Here is the rub, my firebaseService class needs to access posts so it can append items to it from the database (see updated code). What's the best way to access posts from the FirebaseService class?

Comment: I created a new static constant for the class and referenced that. I'm assuming that is correct? With that, everything compiles but I am still not getting the sections to update correctly. The didSet of posts is returning a count of 2 but the section count doesn't look like its being updated.

Comment: No. Now you are turning `FeedController` into a singleton. This is, to keep it PG13, unwise. The singleton is a pattern that needs to be used sparingly, and 99% of the time it applies to certain components of your model layer; virtually never in the VC layer.

Comment: The purpose of your `getAllPosts()` is to wire the database to the array of `posts`. You could turn it into `tieDatabasePostsTo(feedController: FeedController)` that, instead of calling `FeedController.sharedFeedInstance.posts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)`, it calls `feedController.posts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)`. Then the call inside `viewDidLoad()` becomes `tieDatabasePostsTo(self)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: In a way, you are passing that reference so that `FirebaseService` can talk to you. It's similar to a delegation pattern.

Answer (score 0):

So off the bat:

- "FeedController().tableView.reloadData()" is
  instantiating another FeedController. That's not going to work. Where to put the reload call will depend on your requirements. For example if you have a lot of segues occurring where you go back and forth to this UIViewController and the data is being changed in other UIViewControllers, you can reload in an override of viewWillAppear() or the other lifecycle methods. You need to call that on the tableView for the instance of the UIViewController that is loaded into the UIWindow, not what you're doing now.
- Any reason why you're doing a lot of this stuff programmatically rather
  than through the storyboard? Either way is fine but I find storyboard
  to be a nice separation. For example if you used a UITableViewController through storyboard you could have it set up the delegate and dataSource without doing it through code which just looks like ugly boilerplate. You can set these without using a UITableViewController as well, as long as you meet the protocols. Those things that can be handled in the storyboard *should* is what I usually go by.
- Your class is extending UIViewController and implementing those two protocols, why not just extend a UITableViewController? Unless you're manually putting a UITableView on there and need to show something other than a UITableView on that UIViewController there's no reason I can think of to do what you're doing.
- Something else to note is that the way you're doing the PhotoFeedCell and TextFeedCell is kind of weird and gives mixed signals. You're dequeuing a reusable cell and optional casting it and using optional chaining afterwards, both of which implies that you're accepting it may be nil, but then force unwrapping it right after.

Comment: This isn't an answer

Comment: The part where I told you that instantiating another FeedController wouldn't work and where to put it, isn't an answer?

"Where can I run tableView.reloadData() so my tableView datasource updates and gives me the correct could of posts?"

"Where to put the reload call will depend on your requirements. For example if you have a lot of segues occurring where you go back and forth to this UIViewController and the data is being changed in other UIViewControllers, you can reload in an override of viewWillAppear() or the other lifecycle methods."

Comment: I already said that in my post as something I tried and didn't work. As far as you saying where to put it, you have an example that didn't pertain to this. I'm not using segues or even IB for that matter.

Comment: @Jay: You are trying to solve the problem and offer code critique at the same time. It does not provide information about what causes the problem that the OP has.